# scala 3 map tuple to futures of tuple types and back

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, matching, scala-3, match-types

I'm trying to take an arbitrary tuple of `Future`s and return a tuple of the completed future's values, while providing a time limit for the completion of the futures. I'm trying to use `Tuple`'s provided `Map` match type:

```scala
    def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: Tuple.Map[T, Future])(timeout: Long, units: TimeUnit): T = futures match
        case e: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple.asInstanceOf[T]
        case fs: (fh *: ft) => // here, I'd think `fh` would be known to be a Future, specifically Head[Map[T, Future]], and `ft` a Map[Tail[T], Future]
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val vh = fs.head.asInstanceOf[fh].get(timeout, units)
            val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            val remaining = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

            vh *: getAll(fs.tail)(remaining)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
value get is not a member of fh

where:    fh is a type in method getAll with bounds 

            val vh = fs.head.asInstanceOf[fh].get(timeout, units)
```

It seems like the compiler can't tell that `fh` is a `Future`. I'm trying to follow guidance on match types I got from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355407/scala-3-typed-tuple-zipping) of mine, in particular trying to match the value patterns with the match type patterns, but I guess am still missing something.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I got to this version that at least compiles and seems to run properly:

```scala
    def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: Tuple.Map[T, Future])(timeout: Long, units: TimeUnit): T = futures match
        case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple.asInstanceOf[T]
        case fs: Tuple.Map[fh *: ft, Future] =>
            val start = System.nanoTime()
            val vh = fs.head.asInstanceOf[Future[fh]].get(timeout, units)
            val elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start
            val remaining = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

            (vh *: getAll(fs.tail)(remaining, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)).asInstanceOf[T]
```

but a) with the warning:

```
  scala.Tuple.Map[ft, java.util.concurrent.Future]
) @ft @fh cannot be checked at runtime
        case fs: Tuple.Map[fh *: ft, Future] =>
```

which makes sense, I just don't know how to fix it. I'm guessing if I could somehow conjure a `ClassTag[ft]`, but that doesn't seem possible...

and b) the usage needs a type ascription, which makes it much less useable, for example:

```scala
getAll[(String, String)]((f1, f2))(to, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // doesn't compile without [(String, String)]
```

Scastie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7tEjEo6DRIGJDbEwpsps1g)

Comment: I would have converted the tuples to a list and used `Future.sequence` with `Await.result` and the timeout.

Comment: @GaëlJ this would be a `List[Any]`, right?

Comment: @DmytroMitin indeed, didn't think of that. Good catch. Would only be useful if tuple is of the same type for each item.

Answer (score 2):

In match types `case Tuple.Map[fh *: ft, Future]` can make sense. But in pattern matching `case fs: Tuple.Map[fh *: ft, Future]` is just `case fs: Tuple.Map[_, _]` because of type erasure.

Currently on value level match types work not so well (many things can't be inferred). Good old type classes can be better.

<strike>I guess you meant `Await.result` instead of not existing `Future.get`.</strike>

Try to make the method [inline](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html) and add [implicit hints](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#summoning-givens-selectively) `summonFrom { _: some_evidence => ... }` where needed

```
import scala.compiletime.summonFrom
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.{*, given}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.given

inline def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: Tuple.Map[T, Future])(
  timeout: Long,
  units: TimeUnit
): T = inline futures match
  case _: EmptyTuple =>
    summonFrom {
      case _: (EmptyTuple =:= T) => EmptyTuple
    }
  case vfs: (fh *: ft) =>
    vfs match
      case vfh *: vft =>
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        summonFrom {
          case _: (`fh` <:< Future[h]) =>
            val vh: h = Await.result(vfh, Duration(timeout, units))
            val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            val remaining = MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

            summonFrom {
              case _: (Tuple.InverseMap[`ft`, Future] =:= t) =>
                summonFrom {
                  case _: (`ft` =:= Tuple.Map[`t` & Tuple, Future]) =>
                    summonFrom {
                      case _: ((`h` *: `t`) =:= T) =>
                        vh *: getAll[t & Tuple](vft)(remaining, units)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Testing:

```
getAll[(Int, String)](Future(1), Future("a"))(5000, MILLISECONDS) // (1,a)
```

---

Maybe it's better to define `getAll` with `Tuple.InverseMap` (without `Tuple.Map` at all)

```
inline def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: T)(
  timeout: Long,
  units: TimeUnit
): Tuple.InverseMap[T, Future] = inline futures match
  case _: EmptyTuple =>
    summonFrom {
      case _: (EmptyTuple =:= Tuple.InverseMap[T, Future]) => EmptyTuple
    }
  case vfs: (fh *: ft) =>
    vfs match
      case vfh *: vft =>
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        summonFrom {
          case _: (`fh` <:< Future[h]) =>
            val vh: h = Await.result(vfh, Duration(timeout, units))
            val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            val remaining = MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

            summonFrom {
              case _: ((`h` *: Tuple.InverseMap[`ft`, Future]) =:= (Tuple.InverseMap[T, Future])) =>
                vh *: getAll[ft](vft)(remaining, units)
            }
        }
```

Testing:

```
getAll(Future(1), Future("a"))(5000, MILLISECONDS) // (1,a)
```

Now you don't need to specify the type parameter of `getAll` at the call site.

---

Easier would be to define `getAll` recursively both on type level (math types) and value level (pattern matching). Then you don't need implicit hints

```
type GetAll[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match
  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
  case Future[h] *: ft => h *: GetAll[ft]

inline def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: T)(
  timeout: Long,
  units: TimeUnit
): GetAll[T] = inline futures match
  case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
  case vfs: (Future[_] *: ft) =>
    vfs match
      case vfh *: vft =>
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val vh = Await.result(vfh, Duration(timeout, units))
        val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
        val remaining = MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

        vh *: getAll[ft](vft)(remaining, units)
```

Please notice that if you replace the recursive definition of `GetAll` with just

```
type GetAll[T <: Tuple] = Tuple.InverseMap[T, Future]
```

the code stops to compile. You'll have to add implicit hints again.

---

I'm reminding you the [rules](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html#dependent-typing) of match types:

> This special mode of typing for match expressions is only used when the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. The match expression patterns do not have guards
> 2. The match expression scrutinee's type is a subtype of the match type scrutinee's type
> 3. The match expression and the match type have the same number of cases
> 4. The match expression patterns are all [Typed Patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#typed-patterns), and these types are `=:=` to their corresponding type patterns in the match
>    type

The compiler seems not to recognize the match-type definition accompanying a pattern-match definition if we specialize a type parameter along with introducing a type alias:

```
type A[T] = T match
  case Int    => Double
  case String => Boolean

def foo[T](t: T): A[T] = t match
  case _: Int    => 1.0
  case _: String => true
```

compiles and

```
type A[T] = T match
  case Int    => Double
  case String => Boolean

type B[T] = A[T]

def foo[T](t: T): B[T] = t match
  case _: Int    => 1.0
  case _: String => true
```

does and

```
type A[T, F[_]] = T match
  case Int    => Double
  case String => Boolean

def foo[T](t: T): A[T, Option] = t match
  case _: Int    => 1.0
  case _: String => true
```

does but

```
type A[T, F[_]] = T match
  case Int    => Double
  case String => Boolean

type B[T] = A[T, Option]

def foo[T](t: T): B[T] = t match
  case _: Int    => 1.0
  case _: String => true
```

doesn't (Scala 3.2.2). Also the order of cases is significant:

```
type A[T] = T match
  case Int    => Double
  case String => Boolean

def foo[T](t: T): A[T] = t match
  case _: String => true
  case _: Int    => 1.0
```

doesn't compile.

So the easiest implementation is

```
inline def getAll[T <: Tuple](futures: T)(
  timeout: Long,
  units: TimeUnit
): Tuple.InverseMap[T, Future] = inline futures match
  case vfs: (Future[_] *: ft) =>
    vfs match
      case vfh *: vft =>
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val vh = Await.result(vfh, Duration(timeout, units))
        val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
        val remaining = MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, units) - elapsed

        vh *: getAll[ft](vft)(remaining, units)

  case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
```

That's the order of cases as in the definition of `Tuple.InverseMap` https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.2/library/src/scala/Tuple.scala#L184-L187

---

See also

[Scala 3: typed tuple zipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355407/scala-3-typed-tuple-zipping)

[Express function of arbitrary arity in vanilla Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418623/express-function-of-arbitrary-arity-in-vanilla-scala-3)

Comment: I should have clarified, I'm using `java.util.concurrent.Future` (hence the `get()` call), but that's not exactly the point. This is a lot to go through, but thank you for the help, I'll try to understand this!

Comment: @anqit Ah, I haven't noticed. Ok, everything works with java futures too https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/fo7L5npPS4uI5crawOMY8Q/1